# Creating a 2D list of indices from a 1D list

Tags: python

I have a list of integers `x`, and I would like to create a 2D list of integers `y` from it. Here, every row `i` in `y` is a list of the indices of the elements in `x` which have the value `i`.

For example, if:

```
x = [2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4],
```

then:

```
y = [[1], [2, 3], [0, 4], [], [5]]
```

How can I do this neatly in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or using list comprehension:

```
x = [2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4]
y = [[j for j in range(len(x)) if x[j]==i] for i in range(max(x)+1)]
```

Comment: This takes quadratic time, and `range(len(x))` is the wrong range for the outer list comprehension.

Comment: I think that instead of `len(x)`, you need `max(x)+1`

Answer (score 2):

That's simple enough:

```
y = [[] for _ in xrange(max(x)+1)]
for i, item in enumerate(x):
    y[item].append(i)
```

We make a list of the right number of lists, then go through and add each index to the appropriate sublist.

Answer (score 1):

This is my quick solution

```
x = [2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4]

y = []
for i, k in enumerate(x):
    if len(y) - 1 < k: #if our list isn't long enough for this value
        while (len(y) - 1 != k):
            y.append([]) #make it long enough
    y[k].append(i) #append our current index to this values list

print (y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The obligatory numpy answer (perfect case for argwhere):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4])
print [np.argwhere(x == i).flatten().tolist() for i in range(np.max(x)+1)]
```